# Dhcpdiscover sent out when setup ip static on port

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I setup bond1 for eth0 -eth1

```
DEVICE=bond1
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
PEERDNS=yes
DHCP_HOSTNAME=AE-1
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.174.111
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
BONDING_OPTS="mode=1 miimon=100" "
```

But when I check tcpdump at this server send out DHCPDISCOVER to DHCP server.

Did I configure something wrong on this server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `bond1` interface, you probably don't want to use `eth0` and `eth1` individually. The DHCPDISCOVER probably comes from one of the base interfaces.

You have three interfaces, `eth0`, `eth1` and `bond1`. `bond1` is not a real interface in the sense that there is no hardware for this interface, packets for this interface are sent to `eth0` or `eth1`. So you don't want to use `eth0` and `eth1` individually, you just want them to be there for the `bond1` interface. It is possible that your distribution already set up a DHCP client for `eth0` and `eth1`.

Try this to see on which interface you have a DHCP client running.

```
ps waxl | grep dhcp
```

Find the configuration for `eth0` and `eth1` and disable DHCP there.

Comment: Could you explain more details?

Comment: I expanded the answer.